# cannot make static ip in Debian 9

Tags: debian, debian-stretch

Cannot get static ip in my new Debian 9.

in my etc/network/interfaces I have following

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.88.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.88.1   // this is my router ip
network 192.168.88.0   // this is I don't know why, but I saw it in most of instructions
broadcast 192.168.88.255
dns-nameservers 192.168.88.1
```

Then I do this

```
service networking restart
```

And I got error

```
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Answer (score 5):

My Debian version 9

```
uname -a
4.9.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Try with following way, it works for me.
file name: `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    hwaddress 3a:c6:b2:43:7b:ab (you MAC address)
    address   192.168.88.10
    netmask   255.255.255.0
    gateway   192.168.88.1
```

and then restart service:

```
systemctl restart networking.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. 
I installed new instance of Debian and checked settings on fresh system.

The problem was in interface name eth0.
Correct name is ens3.

```
auto ens3
allow-hotplug ens3
iface ens3 inet static
address 192.168.88.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.88.0
broadcast 192.168.88.255
gateway 192.168.88.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.88.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case  I had to write manually resolv.conf file in  and remove existing. Some reason system cannot write a resolv.conf file while set i t up to static ip.

**after that it works!**

Comment: Can you better explain what you mean by `write manually resolv.conf file in`?

Comment: I got a DNS issue after setting static ip. This helped me out. Not a specific answer to this question, but might help others facing this issue when setting static ip